# PostgreSQL Подсчитать количество элементов определенной группы

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть две таблицы:

student

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

student_on_course

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо подсчитать количество оценок и получить следующую таблицу
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На данный момент я написал такой sql запрос:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN t2.student_rating < 30 THEN 'неудовлетворительно'
        WHEN t2.student_rating >= 30 AND t2.student_rating < 60 THEN 'удовлетворительно'
        WHEN t2.student_rating >= 60 AND t2.student_rating < 85 THEN 'хорошо'
        ELSE 'отлично'
    END AS "оценка",
    1 AS "количество студентов"
FROM student_on_course AS t2
-- GROUP BY "оценка"
-- ORDER BY "оценка"
```

результат запроса:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос**:
как дописать запрос до необходимого результата?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фактически вам осталось написать запрос "верхнего" уровня с группировкой по оценке:

```sql
SELECT grade as "оценка", SUM(cc) as "количество студентов"
FROM (
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN t2.student_rating < 30 THEN 'неудовлетворительно'
            WHEN t2.student_rating >= 30 AND t2.student_rating < 60 THEN 'удовлетворительно'
            WHEN t2.student_rating >= 60 AND t2.student_rating < 85 THEN 'хорошо'
            ELSE 'отлично'
        END AS grade,
        1 cc
    FROM student_on_course AS t2
) AS sub
GROUP BY grade
ORDER BY 2
```

Или же можно переписать без подзапроса используя группировку по `CASE` выражению и `COUNT()` для агрегации

```sql
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN t2.student_rating < 30 THEN 'неудовлетворительно'
        WHEN t2.student_rating >= 30 AND t2.student_rating < 60 THEN 'удовлетворительно'
        WHEN t2.student_rating >= 60 AND t2.student_rating < 85 THEN 'хорошо'
        ELSE 'отлично'
    END AS "оценка",
    COUNT(*) AS "количество студентов"
FROM student_on_course AS t2
GROUP BY 1 -- группировка по первой колонке результата "оценка"
ORDER BY 2 -- сортировка по второй колонке ("количеству")
```